# How a P-Channel Mosfet works with a pull-up resistor

Tags: mosfet, resistors, h-bridge

I have been desperately trying for days to troubleshoot this h-bridge I build so I'm trying to completely understand it first. What I don't understand is how `R1` and `R2` in the below image operate. Is the `V+` powering both the source pins of the P-Channel MOSFET's and their gate pins and also the drain of both N-Channel MOSFET's `Q9` and `Q10`? How and when do the resistors `R1` and `R2` come into play?

[image]

Comment: R1 and R2 hold Q1 and Q2 off until you turn Q9 or Q10 on by setting M1_*_Hi to '1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is kind of hard to tell with only a portion of the schematic, but I think they are just pull up resistors that shut the PFETs (Q1 and Q2) off when Q9 or Q10 are not conducting.  They are essentially open drain outputs to operate the higher voltage of the H-Bridge supply from a lower logic level.

[image: open drain]

The NMOS followed by the PMOS is a common way to create a "high side switch" with the higher supply voltage then your logic power supplies would be able to drive directly.

Comment: added full photo

Comment: @MichaelRader What sort of problems are you seeing with it?  If you choose too high of values for R1 and R2, the shut off time will be slow and will result in Shoot-through.

Comment: The problem is it won't go in reverse. The motor goes forward fine but not reverse.

Comment: @MichaelRader The posted reference schematic should work for either direction.  You may need to also add a schematic of your setup exactly as you have it, and your logic you are driving it with for any additional help. Also any voltages you are able to measure in the reverse state.

Comment: Yes I know it should work that way but you asked what problem I was having. that's the problem.